# MariaDB - How to set a field value to a store value from a JSON field

Tags: json, mariadb

I have a set of data set in a field in MariaDB and have been able to work with it well. Now I would like to programatically set the value of another field with the extracted value from my json data field.

Below is an example of how I thought it could be done:

```
UPDATE table
   SET status = JSON_UNQUOTE( JSON_EXTRACT( json_data, '$.previous_status' ) )
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE( JSON_EXTRACT( json_data, '$.previous_status' ) ) IS NOT NULL
```

However I get the error: Unexpected end of JSON text in argument 1 to function 'json_extract'

The data is in the table and I can select it fine, but I can't seem to set the status field to the stored value. Has anyone come across this issue or know how I might achieve updating the status field with the JSON variable data?

EDIT: Here is an example of the JSON data stored.

```
    {
       "previous_status":"ORDER PLACED",
       "integrations": {
          "XX_shippit_sync":"XXXXXXXXX",
          "XX_shippit_data": {
             "carrier_type":"standard",
             "tracking_number":"XXXXXXXXX",
             "parcel_attributes": [{ 
                "qty":1,
                "length":0.24,
                "width":0.16,
                "depth":0.09,
                "weight":0.582
            }],
            "state":"processing",
            "price":"0.0"
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: There are a couple of bugs around [json_extract](https://jira.mariadb.org/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22JSON_EXTRACT%22%20and%20status!%3DClosed) and if not there, it should be reported. It seems very dependant on the `json_data` column so a data extract would be appreciated in a bug report. [json_table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/)  may help

Comment: Can you show us the rows that caused this error? Your SQL seems to be find.

Comment: @adamsmith I have added this to the post now.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag, because you said you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are two different database products, and in particular their JSON features are based on different implementations.

Comment: Maybe a typo?. Change `"XX_shippit_data` to `"XX_shippit_data"`.

Comment: @wchiquito Sorry, yes, just a typo when I was formatting it. The JSON itself is all valid.

Comment: See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-KsZsE_c) for ideas.

Comment: @wchiquito so strange, works in the dbfiddle but the same code doesn't work on my db.

Comment: What exact version of MariaDB are you using?. If you use the [JSON_VALID](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_valid/) function, does it return as valid?, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ytB4fPZ-).

Comment: @wchiquito
 I'm using 10.3 - yes it is valid, I can use the JSON data in any other way, it is only this specific action which isn't working. I copied the exact data from the field into the dbfiddle and it worked, but doesn't work on my db. I might just have to work around it.